# $n+1$ shuffles required for $2^n$ cards, with two withdrawn from deck of cards upon each shuffle

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a deck of $2^n$ cards and shuffled as follows:

Take the bottom and top cards of the deck and place them on the table to start a new deck.

Then take the remaining bottom and top cards and place them on the newly started pile.

Continue this process until all cards are gone from the original pack.

> Prove that after $n+1$ shuffles, the deck of $2^n$ cards will return to their original positions.

(Question was from the book, *Number Theory* by George Andrews)

Eg: for a deck of $8$ cards $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) \to (4,5,3,6,2,7,1,8) \to (6,2,3,7,5,1,4,8) \to (7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8) \to (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$

Comment: Oh please, don't forget to add your thoughts on the problem.  Have you tried approaching this yourself (even if you got stuck, share with us your approach in tackling this problem, preferably along with your working.  Specify where exactly you get stuck in solving this.  Hopefully this is not just a "copy and paste" from the text you refer to?

Comment: I am able to solve it for lots of specific instances, but not the general case.

Comment: Eg: Say you are 1 away from the bottom of the deck in a deck of 2^n cards. After one shuffle you would be 2 away from the bottom of the deck. After 2 shuffles you would be 4 away. After n-1 shuffles you would be 2^(n-1) away from the bottom i.e be at position 2^(n-1). After the nth shuffle you would be at the 1st position. After n+1th shuffle you would be back where you started.

Comment: It is a congruence problem, if you are between [2^(n-1)+1, (2^n)-1] , it is 2xmod2^n, if below that,  it is -2x+1mod2^n. But I am unable to combine them to show after n+1 shuffles you return to original position for the general case

Comment: According to the example, the bottom card 8 remains at the bottom always.

Comment: Regard this as a permutation group of $S_8$ if you have taken any group theory. Try finding the largest orbit of any of these group permutations, and the order of the largest orbit is indeed $n$. This shows you there are $n$ unique permutations before reverting back to the original one.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this yet?

Comment: no,   also in my earlier comment I have shown a cycle of order n+1. But that does not mean order of every cycle in the permutation will divide n+1,which is what needs to be proven. Permutation I am referring to in cycles will be (1,7,6,4)(2,5)

Comment: This problem has to be solved using congruences, there are two congruence functions involved if use numbering from 0 to 7 instead of 1 to 8. -2x-1 mod 7 for 0<= x <=3, 2x for 4 <= x <= 6 mod7. I am unable to provide a combined function, if I could I can solve the problem

Comment: I have posted solution here  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1554888_shuffle_of_2n_cards

Answer (score 0):

I think I have relatively simpler solution here.

The following piecewise congruence can be easily found.

$2x \equiv y \mod{2^n}$ for $x < 2^{n-1}$

$-2x-1 \equiv y \mod{2^n}$ for $x \ge 2^{n-1}$

Now we need to combine these two congruences.

The second one has negative solutions, let's try to find positive solutions, because the positions are non-negative numbers.

$-2x-1 + 2^{n+1} = y$ because this is only valid for $x \ge 2^{n-1}$.

If we take module of $(2^{n+1} - 1)$ for both sides. We get the following congruence.

$-2x \equiv y \mod{(2^{n+1} - 1)}$.

The first congruence can change modulo to $(2^{n+1} - 1)$ because it is already in the range of $x < 2^{n-1}$.

Therefore, we will have the following congruences.

$2x  \equiv y \mod{(2^{n+1} - 1)}$ for $x < 2^{n-1}$
$-2x \equiv y \mod{(2^{n+1} - 1)}$ for $x \ge 2^{n-1}$

These can be converted into $2x \equiv \pm y \mod{(2^{n+1} - 1)}$ for any x.

If we do $s$ number of shuffles, it becomes $2^{s}x \equiv \pm y \mod{(2^{n+1} - 1)}$.

If $s=(n+1)$ then $x \equiv \pm y \mod{(2^{n+1} - 1)}$ so the deck returns to original position.